# Cannot see row counts when executing an SSIS package in VIsual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, appearance

Visual Studio 2013 installed with dark theme.

I cannot see the row counts when a package is executing.

Tried to search for a background change but couldn't find anything.

**Picture:**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

I had Dark theme selected in VS2013 when i installed SSDT.

Switching to Blue theme and then back to Dark fixed the colors and now everything is visible.

Comment: Same thing happened to me, switching to Blue immediately fixed it. Weird.

Comment: i have the same problem yet this solution did not work for me.

Comment: Update - I have fixed this in VS2017 by downloading the Color theme editor from microsoft - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor